# When I run npm init, the package name is always scoped with my organization name by default. How to change this?

Tags: npm, npm-init

[image: npm init bug]

When I run "npm init" the package name always starts from @hackstrap/..., by default. Instead when I run the command package name should be "webpack-demo". How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

```
npm config delete scope --global
```

Running this command helped me solve the issue